# Why Does This format() Function Not Work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code as it was written on a book:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    print ('The ASCII character of 0 is 1' .format('A',65))
```

The output, as the book says, should be `The ASCII character of A is 65`, but it shows me `The ASCII character of 0 is 1`.

Why does it not work? Please help.

Comment: What book are you reading? Can you show us where it says that?

Comment: the book has a typo. There are no placeholders in your format string.

Comment: The placeholders must be written in braces like `{0}`. Maybe you need a better book.

Comment: Try to write ‘{}‘ as a placeholder instead of ‘0‘ and ‘1‘. Content of ‘{}‘ is for optional formatting parameters but the curly brackets serves as the placeholder without any numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set placeholders for where the format method will insert the data:

Like this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    print ('The ASCII character of {} is {}'.format('A',65))
```

Or using keywords

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    print ('The ASCII character of {char} is {num}'.format(char='A', num=65))
```

Or using indices

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    print ('The ASCII character of {0} is {1}'.format('A', 65))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    print ('The ASCII character of {0} is {1}' .format('A',65))
```

The placeholders must be written in braces like {0}.